# How to use two between operator in one SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem in my SQL statement. I just want use multiple between and in operator in my one SQL statement. My code is shown below - what is wrong in the code? Please tell me

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProductByCustomization]
    @Size1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size3 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size4 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size5 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size6 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size7 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size8 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size9 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size10 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size11 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size12 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size13 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size14 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size15 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size16 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size17 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size18 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size19 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Size20 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @CategoryId NVARCHAR(255),
    @Price1 decimal(18,0),
    @Price2 decimal(18,0),
    @Color1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color3 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color4 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color5 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color6 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color7 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color8 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color9 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color10 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color11 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color12 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color13 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color14 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color15 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color16 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color17 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color18 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color19 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Color20 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @DiscountPercentage1 tinyint,
    @DiscountPercentage2 tinyint
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM tblProduct 
    WHERE (PrdPrice BETWEEN @Price1 AND @Price2) 
      AND (PrdOffPercentage BETWEEN @DiscountPercentage1 AND @DiscountPercentage2)
      AND PrdColor IN (@Color1, @Color2, @Color3, @Color4, @Color5, @Color6, @Color7, @Color8, @Color9, @Color10, @Color11, @Color12, @Color13, @Color14, @Color15, @Color16, @Color17, @Color18, @Color19, @Color20)
      AND PrdSize IN (@Size1, @Size2, @Size3, @Size4, @Size5, @Size6, @Size7, @Size8, @Size9, @Size10, @Size11, @Size12, @Size13, @Size14, @Size15, @Size16, @Size17, @Size18, @Size19, @Size20) 
      AND PrdCategoryId = @CategoryId
END
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: You **ABSOLUTELY MUST** learn how to use **table-valued parameters** for your stored procedures! This is just **sheer MADNESS!** ...... Also: use the **most appropriate** datatypes - always - and I really don't think you have any good arguments as to **why** a parameter called  `Size` should be a **2 GB LARGE STRING!** - this should most likely be a **numeric** value - so make it an `INT`, `BIGINT`, or `DECIMAL(p,s)` - don't just make everything a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` because you're too lazy to think about what the **most appropriate** datatype would be!

Comment: @marc i am taking datatype max because i will add M,L,Xl, 6,32 all value which have type nvarchar . i agree that i should not take it max but nvarchar in my requirement

Comment: OK - so you might have sizes that are strings - but do you ***really*** need **a billion characters** ?? I would use a datatype like `nvarchar(10)` or `nvarchar(50)` or something - something that is **reasonable** for this kind of parameter. Again: **do NOT** just simply use `nvarchar(max)` because you're too lazy to think about what length is really reasonable and useful in your scenario! Do put in that extra effort!

Comment: ha ha ha you are saying truth i am little lazy in thinking it so i changed it now because of your advise thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all parameter values are correct. Try put your select query into [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

```
    USE [MakaAnOrderDB]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetProductByCustomization]    Script Date: 1/13/2018 1:51:07 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProductByCustomization]
        @Size1 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size2 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size3 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size4 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size5 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size6 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size7 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size8 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size9 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size10 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size11 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size12 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size13 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size14 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size15 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size16 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size17 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size18 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size19 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Size20 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @CategoryId NVARCHAR(255) ,
        @Price1 DECIMAL(18, 0) ,
        @Price2 DECIMAL(18, 0) ,
        @Color1 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color2 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color3 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color4 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color5 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color6 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color7 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color8 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color9 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color10 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color11 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color12 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color13 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color14 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color15 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color16 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color17 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color18 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color19 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Color20 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @DiscountPercentage1 TINYINT ,
        @DiscountPercentage2 TINYINT
    AS
        BEGIN

            DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
        SELECT  *
        FROM    tblProduct
        WHERE   ( PrdPrice BETWEEN @Price1 AND @Price2 )
                AND 
                ( PrdOffPercentage BETWEEN @DiscountPercentage1 AND @DiscountPercentage2 )

                AND PrdColor IN ( @Color1, @Color2, @Color3, @Color4, @Color5,
                                  @Color6, @Color7, @Color8, @Color9, @Color10,
                                  @Color11, @Color12, @Color13, @Color14,
                                  @Color15, @Color16, @Color17, @Color18,
                                  @Color19, @Color20 )
                AND PrdSize IN ( @Size1, @Size2, @Size3, @Size4, @Size5,
                                 @Size6, @Size7, @Size8, @Size9, @Size10,
                                 @Size11, @Size12, @Size13, @Size14, @Size15,
                                 @Size16, @Size17, @Size18, @Size19, @Size20 )
                AND PrdCategoryId = @CategoryId'


            EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Size1 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size2 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size3 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size4 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size5 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size6 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size7 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size8 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size9 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size10 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size11 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size12 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size13 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size14 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size15 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size16 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size17 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size18 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size19 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Size20 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color1 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color2 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color3 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color4 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color5 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color6 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color7 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color8 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color9 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color10 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color11 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color12 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color13 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color14 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color15 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color16 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color17 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color18 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color19 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @Color20 NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
                        @CategoryId NVARCHAR(255) ,
                        @Price1 DECIMAL(18, 0) ,
                        @Price2 DECIMAL(18, 0) ,
                        @DiscountPercentage1 TINYINT ,
                        @DiscountPercentage2 TINYINT', @Size1 = @Size1,
                @Size2 = @Size2, @Size3 = @Size3, @Size4 = @Size4,
                @Size5 = @Size5, @Size6 = @Size6, @Size7 = @Size7,
                @Size8 = @Size8, @Size9 = @Size9, @Color1 = @Color1,
                @Color2 = @Color2, @Color3 = @Color3, @Color4 = @Color4,
                @Color5 = @Color5, @Color6 = @Color6, @Color7 = @Color7,
                @Color8 = @Color8, @Color9 = @Color9, @Color10 = @Color10,
                @Color11 = @Color11, @Color12 = @Color12,
                @Color13 = @Color13, @Color14 = @Color14,
                @Color15 = @Color15, @Color16 = @Color16,
                @Color17 = @Color17, @Color18 = @Color18,
                @Color19 = @Color19, @Color20 = @Color20,
                @CategoryId = @CategoryId, @Price1 = @Price1,
                @Price2 = @Price2,
                @DiscountPercentage1 = @DiscountPercentage1,
                @DiscountPercentage2 = @DiscountPercentage2

        END
```

Comment: Sir are u using nested query

Comment: @AkshayTomar nope, I just copied your actual select query then I put it into a  declared variable [@SQL]  then pass it through sp_executesql as one of its required parameter. I suspect the between operator doesn't recognized  the datatypes of [@Price ] and [@DiscountPercentage] thats why I am suggesting to try to use sp_executesql . For more clue how sp_executesql works here is the link.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

Comment: Welcome! glad to now it's now working. And will highly appreciate also if you will  kindly marked it as a correct answer. If I satisfactory answer your question, Thanks.